# C Structure Segment Overflow

Tags: c, pointers, linked-list, structure

I have a program in C that creates a two part singly linked list.
I use structures to generate the list, nodes, and node data.
Where the structures are defined as

```
struct TList {
    struct LNode* first;
    struct LNode* last_left;
};

struct LNode {
    struct LData* data;
    struct LNode* next;
};
```

The list looks like `[ A B C ][ D E ]`
Where,
`list->first = "A"` and `list->last_left = "C"`

The following function resets the cursor in the linked list.

```
void reset_list_cursor(struct TList *list) {

    struct LNode *temp, *temp1, *temp2;
    int i = (list_left_size(list) - 1 );

    for (i; i >= 0; i--) {

        temp = list->last_left;
        temp1 = list->first;

        if (temp != NULL) {

            temp2 = temp1->next;
            while (temp2 != temp) {
                temp1 = temp1->next; 
                temp2 = temp2->next;
            }

            list->last_left = temp1;
        }
    }
    list->last_left = NULL;
}
```

However, I am getting a segmentation fault, and I have narrowed it down tho the following lines...

```
void reset_list_cursor(struct TList *list) {

    temp1 = temp1->next; 
    temp2 = temp2->next;
```

I understand you can never call a `temp = temp->next->next`, but when you create a structure in place of the `temp->next` shouldn't it work?

Comment: The `temp = temp->next->next;` is syntactically valid and safe if `temp` and `temp->next` are known not to be NULL (or, more accurately, are known to be valid).

Comment: that means you dereferenced `NULL`. check not `NULL` first and you can avoid it.

Comment: An [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, there's nothing wrong with temp -> next -> next and it's syntactically right too. What you have to make sure in any case involving loops is that you perform a check as to whether the "next" is null or not when stepping into it. Include a condition where you check if temp -> next == NULL when you step into the loop. This will work wonders for you.

That's something like `while(temp1->next!=NULL && temp2->next!=NULL)`

Hope this helps.